# MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqAddressException: 'The invalid scheme was specified: amqps'

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

Trying to configure a .Net Core service to talk to an AmazonMQ - RabbitMQ instance. This is the config I'm using:

https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/rabbitmq.html#amazonmq-rabbitmq

```
                        cfg.Host(new Uri("amqps://b-mdefg-ff37-4e33-855c-577a0c749659.mq.us-westeast-2.amazonaws.com:5432/"), h =>
                        {
                            h.Username("MyUsername");
                            h.Password("XXXXXXXXX");
                        });
```

Nuget packages are:
MassTransit.AspNetCore         v5.5.6
MassTransit.Autofac            v5.3.2
MassTransit.RabbitMQ           v5.3.2
MassTransit.SerilogIntegration v5.1.5

The exception being thrown is:

```
MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqAddressException: 'The invalid scheme was specified: amqps'
```

Upgrading to the latest MassTransit caused a lot of unrelated issues. Any clues as to a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

OK, solution was fairly straightforward, but google gave me nothing so perhaps this will save someone some time. I simply upgraded MassTransit.RabbitMQ to v5.5.6 and it all works now.